# How to Detect LAN or Adapter that is installed by openVPN?

Tags: vb.net, delphi, adapter, vb.net-2010

I am using Visual Basic 2010. I've installed openVPN and its Adapter. I want to make application that will use the Adapter from openVPN. How can I detect it?

I have the code for Delphi. But I don't understand it at all. Its something like this:

```
// INI ADALAH BAGIAN UNTUK MENDAPATKAN NAMA INTERFACE NETWORK

uses WbemScripting_TLB, activex;

type TIWrapper=class
 public
   prop:ISWbemProperty;
   constructor Create(p:ISWbemProperty);
 end;

constructor TIWrapper.Create(p: ISWbemProperty);
begin
  prop:=p;
end;

procedure clear(Adapters:TStrings);
var i:integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to Adapters.Count do
  begin
    Adapters.Objects[i-1].Free;
    Adapters.Objects[i-1]:=nil;
  end;
  Adapters.Clear;
end;

function getPropValue(sprop:ISWbemProperty):string;
var sValue:string;
    count:integer;
begin
  sValue := '';
  if VarIsNull(SProp.Get_Value) then
    sValue := '<empty>'
  else
  case SProp.CIMType of
    wbemCimtypeSint8, wbemCimtypeUint8, wbemCimtypeSint16, wbemCimtypeUint16,
    wbemCimtypeSint32, wbemCimtypeUint32, wbemCimtypeSint64:
      sValue := IntToStr(SProp.Get_Value);
    wbemCimtypeString, wbemCimtypeUint64:
      if VarIsArray(SProp.Get_Value) then
      begin
        if VarArrayHighBound(SProp.Get_Value, 1) > 0 then
          for Count := 1 to VarArrayHighBound(SProp.Get_Value, 1) do
        sValue := sValue + ' ' + SProp.Get_Value[Count];
  end
else
  sValue :=  SProp.Get_Value;
wbemCimtypeDatetime:sValue:=SProp.Get_Value//DateTimeToStr(SProp.Get_Value)
 else
  Exception.Create('Unknown type');
  end; {case}
  result:=sValue;
end;

procedure getAdapters(owner:TComponent; RemoteMachine,RemoteUser,RemotePassword:string; Adapters:TStrings);
var
  Locator: TSWbemLocator;
  SinkClasses: TSWbemSink;

  Services:   ISWbemServices;
  ObjectSet:  ISWbemObjectSet;
  SObject:    ISWbemObject;
  propSet :   ISWbemPropertySet;
  SProp:      ISWbemProperty;
  Enum:       IEnumVariant;
  tempObj:    OleVariant;
 Value:      Cardinal;

 sValue,
 className:     String;
 strQuery:   WideString;
 begin
 className:='WIN32_NetworkAdapter';
 clear(adapters);

 Locator:=TSWbemLocator.Create(owner);
 SinkClasses:=TSWbemSink.Create(owner);
 try
   SinkClasses.Cancel;

if RemoteMachine='' then
  RemoteMachine:='.';// local machine
Services := Locator.ConnectServer(RemoteMachine, 'root\CIMV2', RemoteUser, RemotePassword, '',
  '', 0, nil);
try
  ObjectSet := Services.InstancesOf(className, wbemFlagReturnImmediately or wbemQueryFlagShallow, nil);
  Enum :=  (ObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  try
    while (Enum.Next(1, tempObj, Value) = S_OK) do
    begin
      SObject := IUnknown(tempObj) as SWBemObject;
      propSet := SObject.Properties_;
      SProp:=propSet.Item('NetConnectionID',0);// caption or systemname
      // now get the value of the property
      sValue:=getPropValue(SProp);
      try
        if sValue<>'<empty>' then
        begin
          sProp:=propSet.Item('NetConnectionStatus',0);
          Adapters.AddObject(sValue,TIWrapper.Create(SProp));
        end;
      finally
        SObject:=nil;
        propSet:=nil;
        SProp:=nil;
      end;
    end; {while Enum}
  finally
    ObjectSet:=nil;
    enum:=nil;
  end;

  strQuery := 'SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent within 5 WHERE TargetInstance' +
    ' ISA "'+className+'"';
  Services.ExecNotificationQueryAsync(SinkClasses.DefaultInterface, strQuery, 'WQL', 0, nil, nil);
    strQuery := 'SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent within 5 WHERE TargetInstance' +
    ' ISA "'+className+'"';
  Services.ExecNotificationQueryAsync(SinkClasses.DefaultInterface, strQuery, 'WQL', 0, nil, nil);
   finally
  Services:=nil;// make sure the references are decreased
end;
  finally
Locator.Free;
SinkClasses.Free;
  end; {try}
end;

// AKHIR CODE MENDAPATKAN INTERFACE NETWORK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I just have to detect adapter it from the "System.Net".
Then search the adapter by using the description of the adapter.

```
Dim adapters As System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface() = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    For Each adapter As System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface In adapters
        If adapter.Description.Contains("TAP-Windows Adapter V9") Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(adapter.Name)
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

My VB is a bit rusty (so I am sure there are errors in this), but the Delphi code you showed would roughly translate to something like the following:

```vb
function getPropValue(SProp as ISWbemProperty) as String
  Dim sValue as String = ""
  Dim arr() As String

  If SProp.Value Is Nothing Then
    sValue = "<empty>"
  Else
    Select Case SProp.CIMType
      Case wbemCimtypeSint8, wbemCimtypeUint8, wbemCimtypeSint16, wbemCimtypeUint16, wbemCimtypeSint32, wbemCimtypeUint32, wbemCimtypeSint64
        sValue = CStr(SProp.Value)
      Case wbemCimtypeString, wbemCimtypeUint64
        If SProp.IsArray Then
          arr = CType(SProp.Value, Array)
          If arr.GetUpperBound(0) >= 0 Then
            sValue = CStr(arr(0))
            For Count As Integer = 1 To arr.GetUpperBound(0)
              sValue = sValue & " " & CStr(arr(Count))
            Next
          End If
        Else
          sValue = CStr(SProp.Value)
        End If
      Case wbemCimtypeDatetime
        sValue = CStr(SProp.Value) ' DateTimeToStr(SProp.Value)
      Case Else
        Throw New Exception("Unknown type")
    End Select
  End If
  getPropValue = sValue
End Function

procedure getAdapters(RemoteMachine as String, RemoteUser as String, RemotePassword as String, Adapters as Dictionary<String, ISWbemProperty>)
  Dim Locator as SWbemLocator
  Dim SinkClasses as ISWbemSink
  Dim Services as ISWbemServices
  Dim ObjectSet as ISWbemObjectSet
  Dim propSet as ISWbemPropertySet
  Dim SProp as ISWbemProperty
  Dim sValue as String
  Dim strQuery as String
  Dim className as String = "WIN32_NetworkAdapter" 

  adapters.Clear

  Locator = New SWbemLocator;
  SinkClasses = New SWbemSink;

  SinkClasses.Cancel;

  if RemoteMachine = "" then
    RemoteMachine = "." ' local machine

  Services = Locator.ConnectServer(RemoteMachine, "root\CIMV2", RemoteUser, RemotePassword, "", "", 0, nil)

  ObjectSet = Services.InstancesOf(className, wbemFlagReturnImmediately or wbemQueryFlagShallow, nil)

  For Each SObject as ISWbemObject in ObjectSet
    propSet = SObject.Properties_
    SProp = propSet.Item("NetConnectionID", 0)
    sValue = getPropValue(SProp)
    If sValue <> "<empty>" Then
      SProp = propSet.Item("NetConnectionStatus", 0)
      Adapters.Add(sValue, SProp)
    End If
  Next

  strQuery = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent within 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA """ & className & ""
  Services.ExecNotificationQueryAsync(SinkClasses, strQuery, "WQL", 0, nil, nil)
  strQuery = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent within 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA """ & className & ""
  Services.ExecNotificationQueryAsync(SinkClasses, strQuery, "WQL", 0, nil, nil);
End Procedure
```

Comment: It seems that code (Delphi Code) can't be used on VB.Net even after been translated. Maybe because the lacks of component. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I specifically re-wrote the code to avoid using any components, just the plain vanilla COM objects directly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that. But I've tried it and it's not working. I have found my answer. Really thanks.